# how to use json in java 6 without adding jar file

Tags: java, json, java-6

i'm very new to json and i'm trying to run json with java 6. I wanted to know Is it possible I use Jason without adding jar file in project?

Comment: Yes it is possible, but it's a lot of re-invention of wheel. Why do you don't want to add jar file to a project?

Comment: Without adding a JAR file, you would need to right a parser yourself. What's wrong with adding libraries to the classpath of your application?

Comment: thanks i use jar file

Answer (score 0):

In short the answer is no. Java runtime loads standard jre classes and the libraries (jars) you provide for your project. As long as JSON is not part of java JRE you have to provide JAR so the java would know what it is. Also just for you to note version 6 is very old version. current version is 9. You might want to upgrade

Comment: Current version is 10

Comment: Well, at least upgrade to java 7, but in anycase this is irrelevant to your question